# Only press if 2 images is present

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am using PYautoGUI and im trying to make a script that will solve a puzzle. The puzzle tells me to tap the pair (what ever image there is two of)
I have this code so far:

```
    if pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('TapPair.png', confidence=0.9, region=(689, 250, 640, 1000)) != None:
    for image in images:
        found = list(pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen(image, confidence=0.99, region=(689, 250, 640, 1000)))
        if len(found) >= 2:
            for i in found:
                pyautogui.click(i)
                print("Got a match")
                time.sleep(2)
                break
```

Problem is: it TAPS every image that it matches with... why?

Edit: here is an example of the puzzle[image]

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions, update or answer your previous one instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67168651/press-on-two-images

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes There is alot more content on this question tho?

Comment: Questions rise back to the top when there is activity, duplicate questions create noise.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes Should i delete this one or the other one?

Comment: Personally: I'd prefer keeping old ones, but I don't know if there's an official rule.

Comment: You're making good progress though! Never never give up!

Comment: Okay - im gonna delete the old one - i knew 0 python when i made it. But thanks- working on this for plus 10 hours! not giving up.

Comment: why? because you do nothing to stop it - you get all matches `found = list(..)` - and there can be more then two elements - and next you tap all of them `for i in found` ? Maybe you should use smaller region to search pair only in this smaller region. OR if you want to tap adjacent elements then you should check coordiantes. And if you want to tap only when only two elements are in region then you should use `==` instead of `>=` in `len(found) >= 2:`

Comment: it would be simpler if you would show this puzzle - if it is online game then you could add link.

Comment: @furas Many thanks - i will give this a try.

Comment: I tried len(found) == 2:
It still presses every image it sees and not only the image there is two of... @furas

Comment: i can't run it so I can only sugest to use `print()` to see values in variable - especially image name, size and position. Maybe it finds the same image two times. Or maybe you use wrong images in `locateAllOnScreen` and it finds similar element in two places on the same button. Simply you have to use `print()` to debug code and values.

Comment: Im pretty sure it finds the same image two times - the values seem correct and the images are 100% correct. I dont think this function works the way i want/need it to do....
I think at this point im looking for another way to solve this issue.. Maybe a new algo.

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing the `images` from your code is a list of images that you already saved. So I downloaded your image, and save the sun to be the one to be clicked.

From your code I removed the `region` just to test, but you can use it for a better match. Also I changed `locateCenterOnScreen()` to `locateOnScreen()`.

My puzzle image:

[image: Puzzle]

My sun image:

[image: Sun]

My code:

```
import pyautogui
import time

game = "game.png"
sun = "sun.png"
images = [sun]

print(images)

if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(game, confidence=0.8) != None:
    for image in images:
        found = list(pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen(image, confidence=0.99))
        if len(found) >= 2:
            for position in found:
                pyautogui.click(position)
                print("Got a match")
                time.sleep(2)
```

I also was getting multiple locations differently from each other and more than two after I decrease `confidence`, so try to keep the highest `confidence` you can on `found = list(pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen(image, confidence=0.99))`.

**Also remember to use the images from your screen, because the resolution and pixels will change!**

I splited my code and my image into two windows side by side in my screen. When I `print(found)`, I was getting:

```
[Box(left=1216, top=317, width=130, height=113), Box(left=1529, top=630, width=130, height=113)]
```

After that, it was clicked on both images correctly!